# Getting Blob from database with PHP and using it on an HTML tag

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

Hey so I have a database and my php document is connected properly to it:

```
<?php
$con=new mysqli ("localhost","root","","chroniclemark");
```

...

And I have a query that gets image:

```
$sqlget = "SELECT imagem FROM galeria where idg = 1";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($con,$sqlget) or die ('error getting database');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     $lol = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['imagem'] ).'"/>';

}
?>
```

And that is my php statement. If I `echo $lol;` , the image appears.
Now I need to put this in html img tag.
And this isn't working:

```
<img src='image.php?<?php $row['imagem']?>' />
```

I've tried other things and nothing works.
By the way, the img tag and php statement are in the same file, like this:

```
 </head>
<body>

<?php
    $con=new mysqli ("localhost","root","","chroniclemark");
    if($con->connect_error)
    {
        echo $con->connect_errno;
        die("Database Connection Failed");
    }

    $sqlget = "SELECT imagem FROM galeria where idg = 1";
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($con,$sqlget) or die ('error getting database');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
         $lol = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['imagem'] ).'"/>';

    }
    ?>

    <img src='image.php?<?php $row['imagem']?>' />

                            ...
```

Sorry for my bad English and if you can help, please do. I would be so happy.

Comment: echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['imagem'] ).'"/>'; Works inside the <?php thing and makes image show. But i need to use the <img> tag outside the <?php

Comment: You need to echo the '$lol` variable to the browser. Your example dow no show that.

Comment: `<img src='image.php?<?php $row['imagem']?>' />` is that intended to be used in the same file or another file?

Comment: Is there only one row of data?

Comment: ...is there anyone home? ;-) we ask for clarification but the phone's off the hook.

Comment: ok well I left also.

Comment: @Fred -ii same file

Comment: @Jay Blanchard  yes

Comment: Then you do not need a while loop and this is easy to solve.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard well yeah, i can remove the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the query only returns one row, this simplifies what you need to do. Primarily you can get rid of the `while` loop as you do not need to loop through a result set:

```
<?php
    $con=new mysqli ("localhost","root","","chroniclemark");
    if($con->connect_error)
    {
        echo $con->connect_errno;
        die("Database Connection Failed");
    }

    $sqlget = "SELECT imagem FROM galeria where idg = 1";
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($con,$sqlget) or die ('error getting database');

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $lol = base64_encode( $row['imagem'] );


?>
```

In your question you either forget to do the encoding or didn't know it is required. Now, because the encoding is taken care of, you can output the image in your markup:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?php echo $lol; ?>" />
```

What if you have more than one row? You would put the images in an array and then call them properly later:

```
<?php
    $con=new mysqli ("localhost","root","","chroniclemark");
    if($con->connect_error)
    {
        echo $con->connect_errno;
        die("Database Connection Failed");
    }

    $sqlget = "SELECT imagem FROM galeria where idg = 1";
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($con,$sqlget) or die ('error getting database');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $lol[] = base64_encode( $row['imagem'] );
     }

?>
```

And then something like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?php echo $lol[1]; ?>" />
```

Which would output the second image in the array. Since all arrays start with `0` you could just count or loop or whatever necessary to output the full array of images.

Comment: It's definitely better and simpler without the loop but i'm getting the same thing. Feels like i'm missing something simple.

Comment: @MarkCoelho I made a slight change to the image tag

Comment: i haven,'t, but i'll give it a look

Comment: it works with that change! Thank you so much. If you ever need a logo designed, hit me up

Comment: @MarkCoelho Logo design huh? ;-) I have a bit of competition on my hands *lol*

Comment: @Fred -ii you bet! Thanks for all the help

Comment: @MarkCoelho You're welcome Mark; glad to see Jay helped out, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the src of the image tag with the correct base64 prefix, like you did in the while loop.

This should work, but it is not tested:

```
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $con=new mysqli ("localhost","root","","chroniclemark");
    if($con->connect_error)
    {
        echo $con->connect_errno;
        die("Database Connection Failed");
    }

    $sqlget = "SELECT imagem FROM galeria where idg = 1";
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($con,$sqlget) or die ('error getting database');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
         $lol = $row['imagem'];

    }
    ?>

    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php base64_encode( $lol ) ?>"/>
```

Comment: The only problem here is that you'll overwrite `$lol` each time you loop and will only get the last image. If there is only one row, this shouldn't cause a problem, but doesn't need a loop either.

Comment: Ah, i understand what you mean, but i isn't working quite yet.